# Server crash after seemingly malicious user agent

Tags: security, ubuntu, nginx, user-agent, plesk

I am running Ubuntu with Plesk Onyx. This comes with nginx as the proxy, and Apache with varying options of PHP.

I woke to find that the websites hosted on the server were returning 502 Bad Gateway.

Looking at the logs, one of the websites had a very strange user agent and referrer:

```
() { :;}; echo; echo \x22f5d463ef8e86a21c440eccc11b308080\x22
```

The issue resolved itself with a server restart, but the websites were still down during this time.

Seems like a pretty dangerous exploit. I'm looking for ideas on preventing this at any level (at Plesk, at NGINX, firewalls or other methods). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server has been scanned for ["Shellshock" (CVE-2014-6271) vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-6271).

You can try to mitigate this with any Web Application Firewall (WAF) like mod_security.
You may also try some online scanner to check you system or [verify it locally](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/bash-bug-cve-2014-6271-critical-vulnerability-scaring-internet/).

But it's quite strange that apache down because of some requests of headers it's maybe a performance issue.

It's strongly recommended to apply all system and security updates and always keep system up-to-date.